Read errors mapping Firefox during Ubuntu installation
I'm trying to install Ubuntu as my new OS on my computer, but I'm always running into this error:

rsync: [sender] read errors mapping "/tmp/ tmp7ny_rc_l/mount/var/Lib/snapd/seed/snaps/firefox 4173.snap": Input/output error (5)


You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; but that error is usually the result of invalid ISO (did you verify it before write to your media??) or in my experience more likely a bad write to install/live media (was that verified?) as its having trouble reading the install media thus IO ERROR 5.

This question is similar to: Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also note the non-upvoted answer on that question, ie. on performing media checks... it's what I'd be doing for your unstated Ubuntu product/release before I did anything else, as it's quick & allows you to stop wasting time looking for answers to problems you won't be able to solve...   If no media issues are found, you only wasted a few mins & can explore other problems anyway...

I'm also having this issue, and the comments are fairly useless, you follow the link to verify and it 500 errors, why is the hash not on the download screen, for even basic validation Canonical? but also corrupted download on the exact same file in the ISO seems to be a little coincidental for my liking.
